# JavaScript: How to pass single global object to set of classes?

Tags: javascript, class, global

I have a set of global objects. Those globals can have different settings.

```
var s1 = {
    test1: 10,
    test2: 20
}

var s2 = {
    test1: 10,
    test2: 50
}
...
```

And I have set of classes which use those objects for self configuring. They could look like this:

```
var classA = function(s) {
    this.pA1 = s.test1 + s.test2;
    this.pA2 = Math.sqrt(s.test1);
}

var classB = function(s) {
    this.pB1 = s.test1 * s.test2;
    this.pB2 = s.test1 + s.test2 - s.test1 * s.test2;
}
...
```

Instances of those classes are:

```
var iA1 = new classA(s1);
var iB1 = new classB(s1);
...

var iA2 = new classA(s2);
var iB2 = new classB(s2);
...
```

In reality I have more settings, classes and instances.

How to do this without passing a parameter each time?

Comment: "best option to organize code" seems very broad and opinion-based. Try to avoid that kind of vocabulary. Focus on clear, concrete objectives that do not rely on personal experiences and opinions. Please [edit] it out of your question to replace it with a better goal (such as "how to do this without passing a parameter each time?") with a specified scope for changes (otherwise it might still be too broad as there would be too many possible answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function factory(s) {
    return {
        iA: new classA(s),
        iB: new classB(s),
        iC: new classC(s),
        iD: new classD(s)
    };
}

var set1 = factory(s1),
    set2 = factory(s2),
    ...
```

Alternatively:

```
function factory(constructors, arg1, arg2) {
    var res = {};
    for (var i in constructors) {
        var ctor = constructors[i];
        res[ctor.name] = new ctor(arg1, arg2);
    }
    return res;
}

var constructors = [ classA, classB, classC ];
var set1 = factory(constructors, s1),
    set2 = factory(constructors, s2),
    ...
```